# cp: ./public.generic-pc.icns: Operation not permitted

Tags: macos

On my MacOS Mojave:
I'm trying to change the icon of an SMB Windows File server from the old CRT-BSOD icon to something newer like e.g. the NAS icons.

I'm fine with just using the NAS icon (the com.apple.xserve.icns) but I'm not allowed to replace the public.generic-pc.icns file in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/`

I get an "Operation not permitted" error, even if I sudo cp ....

Comment: Where is it located? Is the place protected by sip?

Comment: Without knowing the path to the file you’re trying to replace, it can’t be said for certain that this issue is caused by SIP, but in general all system files are protected by SIP, so this is likely the issue. If not, please [edit] your question to provide the path to the file and mention that disabling SIP did not resolve the problem. Don’t forget disabling SIP doesn’t give you ownership of the file, so you’ll need to both disable SIP and use sudo.

Comment: I've changed `Bibliotek` to `Library` in the path, assuming that this is the non-localized name. If the path really contains `Bibliotek` in Terminal feel free to edit it back in.

Comment: Nevertheless everything beneath `/System` is protected by SIP so you need to disable this first. Catalina (the upcoming macOS release) will bring additional protection mechanism, not sure whether you will still be able to rename the file there.